# Tips to speed up pub get in containers?

Tags: dart, gcloud, dart-pub

I am running my package tests in containers in GCloud (coupled with Jenkins). Every time a new test run starts, the state of the containers reset (pub's package cache is purged).

Running all the tests take about 10-12 minutes, and running `pub get` takes about the same amount of time - I'd like to shorten it.

It is mostly because of *network communication* that has to happen to resolve and download of packages.

What ways can you think of to make `pub get` go faster?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the Dart-team provided base container?

Curious if you're using this trick: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_docker/tree/master/base#why-run-pub-get-twice

Answer (score 0):

You can preload dependencies in the Dockerfile by adding a line like

```
RUN pub cache add somepackage --version '^1.0.3' --all
```

for each dependency you know in advance.

See

```
pub cache add
```

for possible options.